# How do I retain source lines in tracebacks when running dynamically-compiled code objects?

Tags: python

Say I use [compile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#compile) to create a `code` object from a string and a name:

```
>>> a = compile('raise ValueError\n', '<at runtime>', 'exec')
```

I would like the lines within that string to appear within the traceback (note - the following is run in IDLE):

```
>>> exec(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    exec(c)
  File "<at runtime>", line 1, in <module>
    raise ValueError   <-- This line is what I want
ValueError
```

Alas, they do not:

```
>>> exec(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    exec(c)
  File "<at runtime>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError
```

Without creating a temporary file, how do I make that `raise ValueError` line appear in the traceback?

Comment: Just to be clear -- You want the traceback to point the the line `a = compile(...)`?

Comment: No, I want the traceback to include the corresonding line for the string passed to `compile`

Comment: It looks to me like it _does_ keep the line number... 'File "<at runtime>", **line 1**, in <module>'.  If you add a few newlines before your `raise` statement, you'll see that number increase.

Comment: I want the line contents as well as the line number.

Comment: Ahh ... Ok, I'm understanding now.  Sorry :-)

Comment: @mgilson: Rephrased the title for the hope of clarity

Comment: When compile returns, the literal string you pass is garbage-collected (immediately with CPython).  You have to save the string where the traceback printer will look for it.  The obvious place is in a file whose name you pass to compile.  This is what IDLE does when you 'run' the editor contents.  The other place, at least for now with CPython, is exploited in Eric's answer.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy: Are you sure IDLE does that? The filename `<pyshell#11>` (actually, anything matching `^<.*>$`) is deliberately treated as not a real file when populating `linecache`, so presumably idle is also guilty of this hack

Comment: @TerryJanReedy: Idle does not do that. Idle does what I do (but also a little more, it seems)

Comment: My comment above about 'what IDLE does' was about running code from the editor, where the filename given to compile is a real one.  When I run `exec(a)` in the Windows console at '>>>', `exec(a)` is also missing from the traceback, whereas IDLE does print it (but not the line `exec`ed).  IDLE does this by replacing `linecache.checkcache` with a wrapper than keep `<pyshell#nn>` lines (in the IDLE process).  The user process wraps traceback handling to get `<pyshell#nn>` lines from the IDLE process.  How did you the output above *with* `exec(a)` included?

Comment: The reason IDLE does not show `raise ValueError`is that when the line `a = compile('raise ValueError', ...)` is executed in the *user* process, the standard compile and linecache are used, so that `'raise ValueError'` is lost (as normal).  I could probably change this.  This raises the question of why Python does not do better.  I may ask.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy: See the [link in my answer](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4b2d53def9de6034956efe64afff80df360ff1ac/Lib/idlelib/pyshell.py#L681) - IDLE not only needs to make `checkcache` keep those lines, but it also writes them in a very similar way to my answer.

Comment: _"How did you the output above with exec(a) included?"_ - I ran it in IDLE, as you remark

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File "<string>" traceback with line preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47183305/file-string-traceback-with-line-preview)

Answer (score 3):

Using the undocumented `cache` member of the builtin [`linecache`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html), this seems to work:

```
def better_compile(src, name, mode):
    # there is an example of this being set at
    # https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/linecache.py#l104
    from linecache import cache
    cache[name] = (
        len(src), None,
        [line+'\n' for line in src.splitlines()], name
    )
    return compile(src, name, mode)
```

```
>>> c = better_compile('raise ValueError\n', '<a name>', 'exec')
>>> exec(c)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#50>", line 1, in <module>
    exec(c)
  File "<a name>", line 1, in <module>
    raise ValueError
ValueError
```

---

It turns out this is [pretty much how IDLE does it](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4b2d53def9de6034956efe64afff80df360ff1ac/Lib/idlelib/pyshell.py#L681)

Comment: That's a pretty nasty thing to monkey-patch, and it's going to cause either wrong tracebacks when you compile different code snippets with the same module name or memory leaks if you keep generating new names and caching unbounded numbers of code snippets.

Comment: @user2357112: I'm not suggesting that `better_compile` is always a suitable replacement for `compile`, but with controlled use (creating responsible names) it should be ok

Comment: Also, based on the feedback from @user2357112 -- It seems like this is a good place for a context manager that would remove the cache item when the context is exited.

Comment: @mgilson: Or perhap subclassing the `code` object and cleaning up in `__del__`

Comment: @user2357112: thanks for the warning.  Duplicate names could avoided by having better_compile auto-generate pseudo-filenames such as `<string#nn>`, as with `<pyshell#nn>`.  The lru cache has limits.  For real file names, a file can be re-read after being dumped (but might have changed since imported).  If a traceback needs `<string#1>` after it is dumped, we revert to the present situation -- missing code in the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could write your own exception handler which fills the data:

```
code = """
def f1():
    f2()

def f2():
    1 / 0

f1()
"""

a = compile(code, '<at runtime>', 'exec')

import sys
import traceback

try:
    exec(a)
except:
    etype, exc, tb = sys.exc_info()
    exttb = traceback.extract_tb(tb)

    ## Fill the missing data:
    exttb2 = [(fn, lnnr, funcname,
               (code.splitlines()[lnnr-1] if fn=='<at runtime>'
                else line))
              for fn, lnnr, funcname, line in exttb]

    # Print:
    sys.stderr.write('Traceback (most recent call last):\n')
    for line in traceback.format_list(exttb2):
        sys.stderr.write(line)
    for line in traceback.format_exception_only(etype, exc):
        sys.stderr.write(line)
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<at runtime>", line 8, in <module>
    f1()
  File "<at runtime>", line 3, in f1
    f2()
  File "<at runtime>", line 6, in f2
    1 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Now just wrap that compile & exec into a `smart_exec` function to call every time...

Comment: So your argument here is to wrap `exec` rather than `compile`? That might also be an option

Comment: @Eric Exactly, but, of course, you have to pass the original code (`code`) to the wrapper as well, because compiled `a` did not save the sources.