# Source code for an eval'ed/dynamically generated function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval, code-generation

I am looking for a way to create a Python function from a string containing the source code at runtime, in such a way that the source code is available by inspection.

My current method looks like:

```
src = 'def foo(x, y):' + '\n\t' + 'return x / y'
g = {numpy: numpy, ...}  # Modules and such required for function
l = {}
exec(src, g, l)
func = l['foo']
```

Which works perfectly fine, but the function has no source code/file associated with it. This makes debugging difficult (note the line the error occurs on in foo() isn't shown):

```
>>> foo(1, 0)
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-9df128c5d862> in <module>()
----> 1 myfunc(3, 0)

<string> in foo(x, y)

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

If I define a function in the IPython interpreter, I can get the source using `inspect.getsource` and it will be printed in tracebacks. `inspect.getsourcefile` returns something like `'<ipython-input-19-8efed6025c6f>'` for these types of functions, which of course isn't a real file. Is there a way to do something similar in a non-interactive environment?

Comment: `inspect.getsource` does not work for functions defined in a standard interactive session. If it seemed to work when you tried it, you may have been running IPython without realizing it.

Comment: shouldn't You use `compile` ? . With compile You can first store the compiled code and then exec it when needed. where exec and eval makes evaluation in place without returning objects

Comment: @user2357112 you're correct, I did it in IPython and incorrectly assumed it also worked in the standard interactive interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was able to partially figure this out by digging into the IPython source code. It makes use of the builtin module [linecache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/linecache.html), which contains functions for reading source code from files and caching the results. The `inspect` and `traceback` modules both use this module to get the source of a function.

The solution is to create the function the same way as in the question, but using `compile` with a made-up and unique file name:

```
source = 'def foo(x, y):' + '\n\t' + 'return x / y'

filename = '<dynamic-123456>'  # Angle brackets may be required?
code = compile(source, filename, 'exec')

g = {numpy: numpy, ...}  # Modules and such required for function
l = {}
exec(src, g, l)
func = l['foo']
```

`linecache` contains a variable `cache` which is a dictionary mapping file names to `(size, mtime, lines, fullname)` tuples. You can simply add an entry for the fake file name:

```
lines = [line + '\n' for line in source.splitlines()]

import linecache
linecache.cache[filename] = (len(source), None, lines, filename)
```

The function will then work with `inspect.getsource()`, IPython's `?`/`??` syntax, and in IPython tracebacks. However, it still doesn't seem to work in built-in tracebacks. This is mostly sufficient for me because I almost always work in IPython.

EDIT: see user2357112's comment below for how to get this working with traceback printing in the builtin interpreter.

Comment: If you want this to take effect in a regular (non-IPython) interactive session, [installing `traceback.print_exception` as the traceback printer in place of the default `sys.excepthook`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50515651/why-does-the-python-linecache-affect-the-traceback-module-but-not-regular-traceb/50515847#50515847) should do it.