# How to annotate lines with code when running PyRun_String() in Python C API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, stack-trace, python-c-api

I'm using [PyRun_String()](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_String) from Python C API to run python code.

Passing `Py_file_input` for `start` and for `globals` and `locals` I pass dictionary created with [PyDict_New()](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/dict.html#c.PyDict_New), and for string of code `str` I pass my code.

For example I'm having next code:

```
def f():
    def g():
        assert False, 'TestExc'
    g()
f()
```

Of cause this code is expected to throw an exception and show stack. I print error with [PyErr_Print()](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyErr_Print) and get next stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 4, in f
  File "<string>", line 3, in g
AssertionError: TestExc
```

As one can see this exception stack is missing lines with code, for example if same script is run in pure Python interpreter then it prints next stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    f()
  File "test.py", line 4, in f
    g()
  File "test.py", line 3, in g
    assert False, 'TestExc'
AssertionError: TestExc
```

So it has code annotation e.g. `assert False, 'TestExc'` for last line of stack and `f()` and `g()` for previous lines. Also it has file name (but having file name is not very important).

Is there any way to have this code shown when using PyRun_String()? I expect that I need to use another function for example [PyRun_StringFlags()](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_StringFlags) which has extra parameters `PyCompilerFlags * flags` that I can probably use to tell compiler to save code attached to each line when compiling. But I don't see anywhere documentation for `PyCompilerFlags` and don't know what should I pass.

Also maybe there are other useful flags for `PyCompilerFlags`, for example would be nice to have `test.py` file name instead of `<string>` inside exception stack, probably this behaviour is also tweakable by some of `PyCompilerFlags` values?

Also I was using [exec()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) from built-ins of Python, passing string with program's code to it. But got same exception stack without code annotation. Seems that if it is some interpreter-wide param whether to save code annotation or not.

I also tried to write special function to get current stack, using standard `traceback` and `sys` modules:

```
def GetStack():
    import traceback, sys
    frame = sys._getframe()
    extracted = traceback.extract_stack(frame)
    def AllFrames(f):
        while f is not None:
            yield f
            f = f.f_back
    all_frames = list(reversed(list(AllFrames(frame))))
    assert len(extracted) == len(all_frames)
    return [{
        'file': fs.filename, 'first_line': fr.f_code.co_firstlineno,
        'line': fs.lineno, 'func': fs.name, 'code': fs._line,
    } for fs, fr in zip(extracted, all_frames)]
```

This function returns whole stack correctly, ut inside `code` fields there are empty strings. Looks like `frame` objects don't have code annotation inside theirs `._line` attribute as they probably should, this might be the reason of having no code annotation inside all the functions used above.

Do you know if there is any way to provide code annotation for all stack retrieving/printing operations? Besides manually composing correct stack trace by hand. Maybe there is at least some standard module that allows to set this lines of code somehow at least manually?

**Update**. I found out that `traceback` module uses `linecache.getline(self.filename, self.lineno)` ([see here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4c94d74152a511d977fe26a4f3a32b7352ba9024/Lib/traceback.py#L298)) to get source code. Does anybody know how can I fill linecache with source text from memory with given filename without using temporary file?

Also interesting if raised exception uses `traceback` module to output exception to console or maybe it has its own formatting implementation?

Comment: I think (but I'm not absolutely 100% sure) that it only saves the filename and line number inside the Python bytecode, then uses those to look up the actual source code as needed. Therefore if a file doesn't exist then you can't have the source code.

Comment: @DavidW Then maybe there is at least some way for Python to provide text of source somehow In-Memory? Or if it works with files only then to create temporary file with text. But for temporary file I need to know somehow exactly at what point to provide file, I can't put it for ages till first exception. If there was some python function like `Py_ParseSourceNow()` to parse file exactly at that second when I write temporary file for a second.

Comment: Note that `traceback` is a Python *reimplementation* of traceback printing - it is not the implementation Python uses by default. (You can [*make* it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50515651/why-does-the-python-linecache-affect-the-traceback-module-but-not-regular-traceb/50515847#50515847) use `traceback` if you want.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. After reading [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8a0d9a6bb77a72cd8b9ece01b7c1163fff28029a/Python/pythonrun.c#L1588) of `PyRun_String()` I found out that it is impossible to annotate code-lines of exception (unless I missed something).

Because PyRun_String() sets filename to `"<string>"` and doesn't allow to give other name, while exception printing code tries to read file from file system, and of course doesn't find this file name.

But I found out how to use [Py_CompileString()](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.Py_CompileString) with [PyEval_EvalCode()](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyEval_EvalCode) to achieve line annotation instead of using just PyRun_String().

Basically I create temporary file with the help of [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) standard module. You can create non-temporary file too, doesn't matter. Then write source code to this file and provide file name to Py_CompileString(). After this, lines are annotated correctly.

Below code is in C++, although you can use it in C too with small tweaks (like using `PyObject *` instead of `auto`).

**Important**. For the sake of simplicity in my code I don't handle errors of all function, also don't do reference counting of objects. Also finally I don't delete temporary file. These all things should be done in real programs. Hence code below can't be used in production directly, without modifications.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/j3KbrxzeG)

```cpp
#include <Python.h>

int main() {
    Py_SetProgramName(L"prog.py");
    Py_Initialize();
    
    char const source[] = R"(
def f():
    def g():
        assert False, 'TestExc'
    g()
f()
)";
    
    auto pTempFile = PyImport_ImportModule("tempfile");
    
    auto pDeleteFalse = PyDict_New();
    PyDict_SetItemString(pDeleteFalse, "delete", Py_False);
    
    auto pFile = PyObject_Call(
        PyObject_GetAttrString(pTempFile, "NamedTemporaryFile"),
        PyTuple_Pack(0), pDeleteFalse);
    auto pFileName = PyObject_GetAttrString(pFile, "name");
    
    PyObject_CallMethod(pFile, "write", "y", source);
    PyObject_CallMethod(pFile, "close", nullptr);
    
    auto pCompiled = Py_CompileString(
        source, PyUnicode_AsUTF8(pFileName), Py_file_input);
    auto pGlobal = PyDict_New(), pLocal = PyDict_New();
    auto pEval = PyEval_EvalCode(pCompiled, pGlobal, pLocal);
    PyErr_Print();
    
    Py_FinalizeEx();
}
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_73evamv", line 6, in <module>
    f()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_73evamv", line 5, in f
    g()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_73evamv", line 4, in g
    assert False, 'TestExc'
AssertionError: TestExc
```