# How to override python file lookup for traceback printing?

Tags: python, traceback

I've developed a template engine (https://github.com/hl037/tempiny) that translate a file to python code. Then I call `exec()`.

However, when there are errors in the template, the traceback either print no information (if I don't give a filename to `compile`) or prints the wrong line.

Thus, I would like to change the way the file is retrieved, to use my in-ram version. (by the way, I also can change the file name).

I've checked this question : [File "<string>" traceback with line preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47183305/file-string-traceback-with-line-preview)
...But the answer does not work with the built-in traceback. (and that means that you have to hack globally sys.excepthook, which could cause conflicts with other modules)

I could also use a temporary file, but it would results in some overhead just for getting info only when something wrong happens...

Do you have a solution?

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the code (the parts you think are relevant and offer sufficient content) in the question and provide a clear example of the result you expect and the result you get. It's OK to link to an external location for the full program, but you shouldn't post questions about code that's entirely somewhere else.

Comment: I though the explanation was enough... I will try to add some example code. In meantime, the example code of the linked question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47183305/file-string-traceback-with-line-preview?noredirect=1&lq=1) give good view of the problem, however, the answer given is not fully satisfying, because you need to change sys.excephook globally as answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50515651/why-does-the-python-linecache-affect-the-traceback-module-but-not-regular-traceb?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: The explanation isn't very clear - for example, how does changing the file name have something to do with a traceback apparently referring to a wrong line - it's all very vague. However, not adding the relevant code makes the question on StackOverflow pointless once the original source is no longer available, it's just a rule of the platform - please play by the rules.

Comment: Also, can you make clearer why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47183305/file-string-traceback-with-line-preview doesn't provide the answer you need? It seems pretty complete and appears to answer your question, as far as I understand it from the description above.